# Javascript scope when importing modules

Tags: javascript, module, scope, webpack

Could anyone explain why I can't print `external: bar` in the following example? As far as I know, the imported function `externalFunction` should be added to the global scope, and when invoked, should have the same scope than `localFunction`, isn't it?

**entry.js**

```js
import { f as externalFunction } from './myfunction.js'

function localFunction() {
  console.log('local: ' + foo) // 'local: foo'
  console.log('local: ' + bar) // 'local: bar'
}

foo = 'foo'
var bar = 'bar'

localFunction()
externalFunction()
```

**myfunction.js**

```js
export const f = function() {
  console.log('external: ' + foo) // 'foo'
  console.log('external: ' + bar) // 'ReferenceError: bar is not defined'
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = [
  {
    // define the entry points
    entry: {
      viewer: './entry.js'
    },
    // create a sourcemap file alongside the bundle file for easy debugging
    devtool: 'source-map',
    // Define the path and filename for the bundled modules
    output: {
      path: './',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      // Define all the loaders we want to use
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /.js$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015-without-strict']
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

And then just running this in the browser where the bundle is just added through a  tag.

Comment: Here is a link to a repo with this example:
https://github.com/peto85/js-scope-test

Comment: "As far as I know, the imported function externalFunction should be added to the global scope, and when invoked, should have the same scope than localFunction" where have you read this?

Comment: Let me rephrase that:  "The imported function `externalFunction` should be added to the current scope (which I think it's the global scope in my example). When invoked, it should be able to access the same 'outer' scope than `localFunction`.

Comment: `externalFunction` name would be added to the current Name Binding Context. Which is not global by the way. This name will reference function `f` defined in another module having its own scope that knows nothing about current. Why would adding a reference to a function somehow change function scope? The only reason you are able to access `foo` is that you made it global unlike say `bar`.

Comment: I think I just had my 'a ha!' moment and finally understood how scope works in Javascript...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access variables declared in dynamically imported JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61892074/access-variables-declared-in-dynamically-imported-javascript)