# Access variables declared in dynamically imported JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, dynamic-import

I am working on Single Page Architecture (SPA) Web application. I am have implemented functionality to dynamically load different pages of application.

This is what my **spa.js** looks like

```js
var spa = {
    init: async () => {

        await import('./page.js')
        spa.data['page'].apply()
    },

    register: (page, data) => {
        spa.data[page] = data
    },

    data: {},
}

window.onload = () => {
    spa.init()
}
```

And this is what my **page.js** looks like

```js
const pageData = {
    apply: () => {
        document.body.innerHTML = getMSG()
    }
}

function getMSG() {
    return "hello message!"
}

spa.register('page', pageData)
```

The working process explained:

- Initially **spa.js** loads. *spa.data* is empty
- It initiates *spa.init()*, which loads **page.js**
- **page.js** registers its data to *spa* variable
- Now control jumps back at **spa.js** and from *spa.data* for page, it will execute *apply()*

This works fine. But here's a strange thing!

The *apply()* method has access to bare *getMSG()*, but when I try to execute *getMSG()* it via browser's developer console I get ReferenceError implying that *getMSG()* is not defined at all! Same goes with our *pageData*

Here is the hosted heroku app, you can try - [dyn-import](https://dyn-import.herokuapp.com/)

Although it is very good as I don't have to worry about clashing functions in different files, I want to know how this is happening.

Can someone explain how can I access methods and variables defined in **page.js**. I am aware about exports, but it is somehow possible without exports!

Comment: What do you mean by executing with console? you want it to be globally accessible?

Comment: `await import('./page.js').then()` is very strange. Either you `await something()`, or you go Promise-style with `something().then()`. But not both

Comment: @ThakurKarthik By console, I mean browser console (F12, developer console). When I try to access the method via console, it says undefined. But the script can access it, as if it's global. My question is is it global or not? If yes, why it doesn't work in console, if not how can apply method access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly access functions and variables defined in the module if they are not exported.

Reason why `spa` variable is accessible globally is because **`spa.js` is normal script**, referenced in the HTML document head.

```html
<head>
    ...
    <script src="./spa.js"></script>
</head>
```

If you, on the other hand, `import` script, variables are in different scope, unless you export them. So **`page.js` is treated as a module**.

You could, of course, attach function `getMSG()` to the global `spa` variable, or `pageData`, but both would be workarounds.

```js
spa.getMSG = getMSG;
```

You can read more about differences between modules and standard scripts here - [MDN JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Comment: But the call to apply() function in spa.init() can access getMSG(), which is part of module and not exported.

Comment: Yes, because you attached `pageData` to `spa` manually using `spa.register('page', pageData)`. Do similar for the function. For example: `spa.getMSG = getMSG`.

Comment: Nenad, even if I don't attach getMSG to spa it fulfils my requirements. My question is more about why it works in spa without attaching, and why it doesn't in console?

Comment: I already told you everything. You can think of it as `private` function inside of `page.js`. It works in `spa` because you wrapped the function in `pageData.apply` and then you attached `pageData` to `spa` with `spa.register('page', pageData)`. Not sure what is not clear to you.

Comment: Thanks! It's clear now. It would be really helpful if you could link to some docs related to scoping of imported modules in your answer above